# My script creates multiple files for mails with multiple recipients

Tags: postfix-mta

What  I did is really simple to write incoming mail to file:

1. mailbox_command = path/to/mycript.py
2. luser_relay = unknown   add,  unknown = "|/path/to/myscript.py"    to aliases file.
3. myscript.py reads from stdin line by line and writes the lines to file.

These lines redirects any incoming mail, no matter whether user exists 
or not, to my script. My script reads data from stdin and writes it to file. If my script receives mail with one recipient it creates one file. But if it receives with 2 recipients, it creates 2 files. What I want is that it still should create 1 file. I want to make number of files created by script not related to number of recipients but related to number of messages received.

Thanks,

Comment: "If my script receives mail with one recipient it creates one file. But if it receives with 2 recipients, it creates 2 files. What I want is that it still should create 1 file." --> change your script such that it creates one file only.

Answer (score 0):

You can store in a file the email count, or just save each file, using epoch as filename

I would do it like this in ruby.

```
# read from stdin, and save a timestamp filename
IO.write Time.now.to_i.to_s,STDIN.read
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it in a little bit more detail. I could not understand. Thanks.

Comment: I guest your answer is to find a way to archive the email in diferent files. The script, just call the function Time.now.to_i generating an epoch,for example: Time.now.to_i.to_s => "1403699657". The shoul be a function like that in python. Then write it to a file, for example a file named: filename = "%s.eml" % Time.now.to_i.to_s

Comment: Now the problem is, change mail_box command for a transport, because mailbox_command is executed for each mail individual. You should use transport pipe and flag it for feed with all the destinations on the fly not for each recipient.